# How to split the display screen of any app on Android?

Tags: android, screen

I'm looking for a way to split my android screen into two identical (or not) parts on apps I have downloaded, but of which I don't have access to source. Basically, anywhere you go on your phone, you see a split screen.

Applying a transformation matrix on the main screen would be perfect, but I can't find any API for such a thing. I found this app that does color tinting:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kovit.p.filteryourscreen

If they do that with a transformation matrix, it means it's possible to rotate, blur or split your screen however you like.

Do you think it's possible? It would be very helpful if anyone could direct me to a general direction for accomplishing this.

Answer (score 1):

> Basically, anywhere you go on your phone, you see a split screen.

This is not possible, except by:

- Downloading the Android source code
- Making *substantial* modifications to the operating system, which assumes only one activity can have the foreground from an input standpoint at a time
- Creating a modded ROM based upon your modified source code
- Installing that modded ROM on your device

Answer (score 1):

The app you mentioned, uses the permission `DISPLAY SYSTEM-LEVEL ALERTS` which allows them to show a special kind of window that's always in front of all other windows.

I guess, they span such a Window fullscreen, make it more or less transparent and add the configured filter and pass all touch events etc. 'through' the window to the ones behind.

But they do not modify the window behind, so it is quite different from what you are trying to achieve and what is, according to CommonsWare, impossible.